# Undefined Index on $_GET variable, its set but still doesn't works?

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

I am redirecting from here

```
<a href="update_post.php?updid=<?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>">Update</a>
```

and code which shows error is

```
<?php include('../includes/connections.php'); ?>
<?php
try{
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$title = $_POST['title'];
$post = $_POST['post'];
$dates = $_POST['date'];
$sql = 'UPDATE `blog`.`contents` SET `titles` = :title, `posts` = :post, `dates` = :date    WHERE `contents`.`id` = :idendity';
$result = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$result->bindValue(':title',$title);
$result->bindValue(':post',$post);
$result->bindValue(':date',$dates);
$result->bindValue(':idendity',$_GET['updid']);
$result->execute();
$count = $result->rowCount();
    if($count == 1){
        header('location: index.php');
    }else{
        echo 'Problem Occoured';
    }
}
}
catch(PDOException $e){
echo "Problem: " .$e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

error which is shown:-Notice: Undefined index: updid in C:\xampp\htdocs\myblog\admin\update_post.php on line 13
Problem Occoured

```
<form action="update_post.php" method="post">
    Title:<br/>
    <input style="height:40px;" size="110" type="text" name="title" /><br />
    Post:<br />
    <textarea rows="30" cols="85"  name="post" ></textarea><br />
    Date:<br />
    <input type="text" name="date" /><br/ >
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the URL looks with `update_post.php?updid=something`?

Comment: You can't reach that condition by clicking on a link. It's literally not possible: the link will always result in a `GET` request, but that point in your code is only accessed if the request uses `POST`. How is the page actually accessed? A form submission?

Comment: yes by form submission and that is the reason i am checking for if submit isset or not.

Comment: @Shashi Your `form` tag should be like: `<form action="update_post.php?updid=<?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>" method-"post"><!-- other stuff -->`. Post form html, please.

Comment: and i have used the same method for deleting posts and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> yes by form submission and that is the reason i am checking for if submit isset or not.

You should include `$_SESSION['id']` in a hidden field in the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="updid" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>" />
```

... and change:

```
$result->bindValue(':idendity',$_GET['updid']);
```

... into:

```
$result->bindValue(':idendity',$_POST['updid']);
```

**Edit**

First of all, your question above has error. As mentioned in the comment, it's not possible that `isset($_POST['submit'])` will return `true` if you click on a link.

`$_POST` will have values when you access the page by submitting a form that has `post` in the `method` part.

As for `$_GET`, its values are taken from the query string of a URL:

```
http://yourpage.php?foo=bar&bar=foo
```

`bar` is the value of `$_GET['foo']`

`foo` is the value of `$_GET['bar']`

I've searched for basic $_POST/$_GET explanation but unable to find one :-D

Comment: Thanks alot this worked, can you please explain them why it is so , i am fairly new to PHP just practicing from 2 months.

Comment: any links or material will be helpful

Comment: Although isset($_POST['submit']) was not intended for link , it was for submit button in form.
anyways i understood rest of the things you explained ,thanks

Comment: @Shashi that would never happen unless you had a hidden element with `name=submit`